# Why won't my laravel development server start

Tags: laravel

I have installed laravel using composer but my development serve won't start serving. What could be the issue?
[image]

Comment: what is the error when you click on http://http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: @OssamaAbd "An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be working, check on your browser

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

if it still doesn't work, serve it on the `0.0.0.0` IP number

also  check port is open or not

example custom host and port

```
 php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=1233
```

if not working still ,likely port not accessable

Comment: Your welcome have nice works